# Qual a diferença entre o while, for, do while e foreach?

Tags: php, loop, foreach, while, for

Qual a diferença entre o `while` , `do` `while`, `for` e `foreach` no PHP, pois dão a impressão que tem a *mesma funcionalidade*.

Todos eles podem ser usados para se criar um *loop* ou tem outras finalidades?

Como ficaria um exemplo simples de uso de cada um?

Comment: O [princípio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow#Loops) é o mesmo para todas as linguagens de programação. [Já que escolheu o PHP, recomendo estudar o básico em C primeiramente.](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson3.html)

Comment: Escolhi php por ser a linguagem que mais uso, e para a pergunta não ficar ampla de mais. Agradeço a recomendação.

Comment: Todos eles **são** loops (instruções de controle de fluxo). For-each é o mais extravagante, pois é específico para percorrer coleções (Abstrações de linguagens de alto nível, como o Python, JS, PHP, Ruby e outras derivadas do C), mas também é um loop. Tudo o que se faz com um do-while, for e for-each dá pra fazer com um simples while. Ao traduzir para o Assembly, todos resumem-se à instrução JMP (Jump).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Todos eles são usados para laços. Até existem alguns usos "criativos", mas sempre serão repetições controladas.

## `while`

A estrutura de controle de fluxo `enquanto` repete o bloco de comandos até a condição estabelecida resultar em falso. O bloco pode nunca executar já que a condição é anterior, e nesse ponto específico é como um `if`, onde entra no bloco apenas se a condição for verdadeira, a diferença para o `if` é que ao final do bloco ele volta para o início para testar novamente a condição, e não tem um `else`, pelo menos em PHP.

Ele é usado em situações que você não sabe o início e fim de nada, algo que você tem pouco controle do que determinará até quando repetir.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $html .= $row;
}
```

## `do...while`

É basicamente a mesma coisa do `while`, mas a condição está no final, portando é garantido que o bloco execute ao menos uma vez.

```
do {
    //executa algo
} ($condicao);
```

Seria o mesmo que fazer:

```
while (true) {
    //executa algo
    if (!$condicao) {
        break;
    }
}
```

## `for`

É como o `while`, mas é uma forma ainda mais estruturada onde uma ação de avanço é aplicado ao final de toda iteração. Em geral é usado para ir de um ponto a outro onde se sabe o início e o fim, além de ter uma instrução de avanço em cada passo.

Além da condição existem duas outras informações na sua construção:

- uma que inicializa alguma variável ou eventualmente executa alguma ação **dentro do escopo do bloco**, isso é executado apenas uma vez
- outra que é executada todas as vezes que termina uma passada no bloco e não saia dele forçadamente. O mais comum é fazer algum incremento ou decremento aritmético ou geométrico, mas pode ser usado para outras operações, inclusive só chamar alguma função que precise de garantia que sempre será executada em cada repetição. Exemplo:

  ```
  for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
  ```

descrevendo:

```
for ($i = 0; // inicialização, executa apenas uma vez
     $i < 10; //condição é avaliada em cada passo da repetição, antes de iniciar o bloco
     $i++) //execução de passo
```

Note que o passo a ser executado ocorrerá até mesmo se um comando `continue` for aplicado dentro do laço. Algumas pessoas pensam que o `for` é o mesmo que:

```
$i = 0;
while ($i < 10) {
    //executa algo
    i++;
}
```

E até é, desde que não tenha um `continue` dentro do laço. Isto já é diferente:

```
$i = 0;
while ($i < 10) {
    //executa algo
    if ($condicao) {
        continue; //o incremento não será executado, no for seria
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Também há outra diferença que a variável `$i` está fora do escopo do laço. Isso pode ser desejável, mas o no `for` pode ser feito também, basta que a inicialização seja feita fora. Se estiver no escopo do bloco essa variável não poderá ser usado depois que ele terminar de executar.

Todos os 3 elementos do `for` são opcionais. Não precisa inicializar nada se não tem nada útil para fazer. Não precisa ter o passo, o que indica que talvez o `while` fosse mais adequado em muitas situações assim. E nem a condição precisa ser executada, o que é raro, mas tem utilidade. Há quem goste de usar uma construção `for` para estabelecer um *loop* infinito, que obviamente precisa ter algo interno que determine seu fim:

```
for (;;) { //faz algo aqui e deve ter um if com break }
```

Esses são os principais motivos para preferi-lo. Mas as pessoas também usam porque economiza uma linha nesse padrão em comparação ao `while`.

É possível inicializar e "incrementar" mais de uma variável ao mesmo tempo. Exemplo:

```
for ($x = 1, $y = 1; $x <= 10; $x++, $y++) {
    if (($y % 2) == 0) {
        $impar += $y;
    }
    $total += $x;
}
```

A condição deve ser única já que ela tem que resultar em um booleano único. Claro que pode usar operadores relacionais como `||` e `&&`, como em toda expressão condicional, assim é possível comparar as duas variáveis ou outro elementos pertinentes.

## `foreach`

É uma repetição controlada de início ao fim com um padrão específico em coleções de dados.

Não há uma condição, ele varre uma coleção de dados do início ao fim (essa coleção pode ser um subconjunto de uma coleção maior). Qualquer dado que possua vários elementos pode ser usado, normalmente um *array* ou *string* é o mais comum. É menos comum, mas é possível até mesmo iterar sobre um objeto e pegar cada membro da classe.

É uma forma mais controlada e abstrata de execução e evita alguns problemas que o programador mais descuidado (o que é normal) pode acabar fazendo em repetições mais "livres". Em geral é preferida quando vai avaliar toda uma sequência de dados.

É possível avaliar uma fração da coleção de dados através de alguma função que forneça o início e fim diferentes do normal.

Em alguns casos o `for` pode ser mais adequado por poder controlar melhor como deve proceder a interação e acesso aos elementos. Pelo `for` você varia o índice de acesso aos elementos da coleção, no `foreach` você recebe o elemento em si. Pode ser feito, mas é um pouco mais complicado fazer certo, proceder contagens (incrementos simples) no `foreach`.

Note que se você criar uma coleção de dados própria, deverá atender certos requisitos para que ela funcione adequadamente com o `foreach` que espera um padrão destas coleções.

Ele deve ser preferido sempre que for o mais adequado. O `for` e principalmente as duas foras de `while` não devem ser usados em coleções a não ser que precise fazer algo fora do normal que o `foreach` atende bem.

```
$cores = array("azul", "amarelo", "verde", "vermelho");
foreach ($cores as $cor) {
    echo "$cor<br>";
}
```

Tem função pronta que faz exatamente isso e algumas pessoas preferem essa forma ainda mais abstrata, mas nem todo problema é tão simples.

Isso poderia ser escrito com `for`, mas não é o mais adequado:

```
$cores = array("azul", "amarelo", "verde", "vermelho");
for ($i = 0; i < count($cores); i++) {
    echo "$cores[$i]<br>"; //note o índice sendo usado
}
```

Ou poderia ser feito com o `while` com o mesmo resultado já que não tem um `continue` e o escopo de `$i` não é importante:

```
$cores = array("azul", "amarelo", "verde", "vermelho");
$i = 0;
while (i < count($cores)) {
    echo "$cores[$i]<br>";
    $i++;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Syntax/Loops.php).

O `do...while` já ficaria complicado demais reproduzir o mesmo, mas é perfeitamente possível, como demonstrado no exemplo no começo deste *post*, apensar de ficar feio e não trazer vantagem alguma.

## Conclusão

Procure usar a melhor ferramenta para cada caso. A que dê mais semântica do que deseja fazer.

Answer (score 4):

**Resposta:**

Todos eles podem ser usados para se criar um loop, no entanto existem alguns padrões para utilizar um ou outro comando.

**Padrões:**

1. Caso você precisar iterar uma lista de objetos, os comandos mais apropriados são o `foreach` e o `for`. Caso os objetos da lista possuírem atributos é mais recomendado o uso do `foreach` porque é só se preocupar em iterar a lista sem precisar ter uma variável de controle como é o caso da variável `$i` que iremos ver em exemplos abaixo.
2. Em outras situações, como, por exemplo, se é preciso tratar apenas uma variável e *NÃO* uma lista de objetos os comandos `while` e `do while` se aplicariam melhor nessa situação.

> **While**: Em Português significa Enquanto, se determinada expressão for verdadeira o loop continua, caso contrário sai fora do loop.

**Exemplo:**

```
<?php
    $i = 0;
    while ($i != 10){
        $i = $i + 1;
        echo $i;
    } 
     echo "Fim de execução";
?>
```

Quando a variável `$i` for igual a `10` resultando em `falso` dentro do `while` o loop será encerrado, porque `10` é igual a `10` e não diferente.

> **Do While:** Comparado ao comando `While` mencionado acima, o que esta dentro do comando `Do While` sempre será executado pelo menos uma vez, isso porque a verificação se deve ou não continuar iterando fica abaixo. Repare que no exemplo acima, se a variável `$i` fosse inicializada com o valor `10` não entraria dentro do loop.

**Exemplo:**

```
<?php

    $i = -1;

    do {   

        echo $i;
        $i++;

    while ($i != 0);    
?>
```

O comando acima será executado apenas uma vez, isso porque a variável `$i` foi instanciada com o valor `-1` e dentro da iteração faço ela incrementar mais 1, ficando igual a 0, e quando cair no comando `while` logo abaixo a variável `$i` não será diferente de 0, saindo do laço de repetição.

> **For:** A sintaxe é diferente dos comandos mencionados acima, geralmente é utilizado quando é preciso percorrer um `Array`, porque uma variável que contém um `Array` possui um número de elementos que há dentro.

**Exemplo:**

```
<?php

     // Array com 3 (três) elementos
     $cachorros = Array("Pastor Alemão", "Cocker Spaniel", "Pitbull");

     $tamanho_array = count($cachorros);
     for ($i=0; $i < $tamanho_array; $i++){
          echo $cachorros[$i]."<br>";
     }
?>
```

No exemplo acima criei uma variável com uma lista de raças de cachorros, guardei na variável `$tamanho_array` o número de elementos que tem dentro da lista, ou seja, o número de raças que tem dentro do array e utilizando o comando `for` percorri essa lista sempre incrementando no próprio comando o valor de `$i` e quanto o valor de `$i` for igual ao número de raças que tem dentro da lista sai do loop.

Foreach: Semelhante ao comando `for`, no entanto não precisamos ficar incrementando uma variável como é o caso do `$i`, será utilizado geralmente para percorrer uma lista que pode vir do banco de dados, funciona apenas com listas e objetos.

```
<?php

     $pessoas = // Recebe uma lista de pessoas do banco de dados.

     foreach($pessoas as $pessoa){
          echo "Nome: ".$pessoa->getNome()."<br>";
          echo "Sexo: ".$pessoa->getSexo()."<br>";
     }

?>
```

O comando acima sairá do loop quando o comando `foreach` percorrer todos os elementos da lista.

**Referências:**

[Manual do PHP - While](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.while.php)

[Manual do PHP - Do While](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.do.while.php)

[Manual do PHP - For](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.for.php)

[Manual do PHP - Foreach](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.foreach.php)

Answer (score 3):

Todos eles tem realmente a mesma funcionalidade com pequenas diferenças.

While: Executa o loop enquanto a condição for verdadeira.

```
// Contar de 1 até 10
$contar = 1;
while($contar <= 10){
   echo "$contar";
   $contar++;
}
```

Do While: Executa o loop primeiro e depois verifica a condição.

```
// Contar de 1 até 10
$contar = 0;
do{
    $contar++;
    echo "$contar";
}while($contar <= 10)
```

For: Executa o loop enquanto a condição for verdadeira, porém você pode instanciar as variaveis contadoras dentro da estrutura do loop.

```
for($contar = 1; $contar <= 10; $contar++){
    echo "$contar";
}
```

Foreach: Executa o loop sobre os elementos de um array.

```
$contar = range(1, 10);
foreach($contar as $valor){
    echo "$valor";
}
```