# For com um ";" no começo do laço, o que significa

Tags: c#, sintaxe, for

Peguei um código com um for assim:

```
for (; indField > 0 && indMask > 0; )
```

O que significa esse `";"` no início e fim do comando?

Comment: O ideal seria verificar locais onde as variáveis indField e indMask são utilizadas anteriormente. Não tenho como testar no momento, mas creio que seja o seguinte: O for tem a estrutura (inicialização; condição; incremento), no seu exemplo ele tem apenas a condição.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

O `for` tem 3 "partes":

```
for ( executar antes de começar ; condição para executar ; executar ao fim da iteração )
```

Você só precisa preencher o que precisar. Mas tem que por os `;` de qualquer forma.

No caso, o autor do código não precisou fazer nada para inicializar o loop, só interessou para ele a condição para iterar, que é o ítem do meio.

Da mesma forma, se ele quisesse um *loop* infinito, bastaria omitir também a condição:

```
for( ;; ) {
   // ficarei em loop até o fim dos tempos (ou alguma coisa externa me parar)
}
```

Answer (score 15):

A pessoa deveria ter usado um `while` neste caso, afinal só tem uma condição e mais nada. O mais sensato seria:

```
while (indField > 0 && indMask > 0)
```

Nesse caso a estrutura não deveria ser um `for` porque não usa o que ele tem de vantagem. A confusão do AP que originou a pergunta foi justamente porque o programador não seguiu o preceito básico de fazer o que é mais semanticamente mais correto, que é o que ele e todos deveriam fazer. No mínimo é [mais elegante](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173216/101) usar o `while` aí.

Tecnicamente, significa que não quis inicializar uma variável, como é comum fazer em um `for`. também não quis executar nada em cada passo da iteração do laço, notou que não há nada também depois o último `;`?.

Um `for` é:

```
for (           //o comando
    int i = 0;  //a inicialização da variável (geralmente, pode ser qualquer ação)
    i < 10;     //a condição de término do laço (sempre tem que ser um resultado booleano
    i++         //o passo a executar em cada interação, o incremento é muito comum
) {             //fecha o comando e abre o bloco de execução
```

Note que o `for` é sempre composto por 3 [ações](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173379/101) diferentes e depois costuma ter um bloco do que deve ser executado no laço. Em tese todas as 3 partes podem ser omitidas, dependendo do que deseja.

Outras coisa que poucas pessoas sabem é que pode haver mais de uma expressão em cada uma dessas partes, se separar por vírgulas, e isso nem é exclusivo do `for`, vale em qualquer contexto onde se espera um *statement*. Exemplo:

```
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < 10; i++, j++) { ... }
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Syntax/For.cs).

Até a condição pode fazer isso, mas só a última expressão booleana será considerada como resultado final para determinar se o laço deve continuar ou não.

Então cada um dos 3 *statements* do `for` pode ter de zero à "infinitas" expressões.

Veja [Qual a diferença entre o while, for, do while e foreach?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/157512/101). É outra linguagem, mas vale o mesmo.

Comment: Bem lembrado de avisar que é caso de while.

Comment: Alguém não gostou e negativou. Acho que a pessoa deve gostar de usar o `for` onde o `while` é melhor :)

Comment: Sua resposta teve parte baseada em opinião, e não foi ao foco, acho que julgar programadores não é o foco do site.

Comment: @MarcoViniciusSoaresDalalba ter opinião não é um problema, a resposta não pode ser baseada em opinião e o que foi respondido está correto e não é baseado em opinião.  O voto é opinativo. Ser foco e não poder são coisas distintas. O foco da resposta não é opinativo. Na verdade mesmo o ponto que está dizendo não é opinativo. Eu dei duas possibilidades, ou a pessoa não conhece o que é mais adequado ou ela fez de propósito porque ela gosta de fazer "diferente", não existe outra opção. Eu não disse o que é a pessoa que fez isso, então eu não julguei a pessoa, dissertei sobre a escolha da ação.

Comment: @MarcoViniciusSoaresDalalba mas eu aceito sugestões, se você tiver uma terceira opção válida que eu tenha esquecido para justificar o for usado como while, comente, que se for coisa sensata eu posso melhorar a resposta. Comentário que acrescenta valor é sempre bom.

Comment: E o seu comentário que por ter recebido downvote julga quem deu o downvote? Você pode até não ter a intenção de julgar mas está fazendo isto.

Comment: @MarcoViniciusSoaresDalalbasim, Você está julgando, está dando sua opinião, e eu não reclamo disso, tá ótimo. Assim como o downvote dado está fazendo um julgamento. Eu não vou fingir que não há julgamentos o tempo todo na vida. Os julgamentos precisam ser pelas coisas certas, com critério, com justiça. Eu não tenho como discutir com uma pessoa que faz um julgamento baseado no gosto dela. Se pessoa não gosta do que eu escrevi, não posso fazer nada. Se ela disser que votou porque tem erro na resposta, aí eu posso concordar ou debater e posso dizer que uma resposta sem erro não merece negativo.

Comment: Na minha visão é interessante criticar códigos, afinal alerta ao programador qual a melhor opção entre as tantas existentes. A partir do momento em que o código é exposto em uma pergunta ou em qualquer outro lugar, ele está sujeito à julgamentos, da mesma forma que as respostas, comentários e opiniões também estão.

Comment: @SérgioTorres de fato, principalmente quando se trata de ensinar outras pessoas. Programar bem ou mal em princípio é problema de cada um (e de quem contratou cada um kkk), mas ao propagar conhecimento no site, passa a ser problema de todos nós ao menos indicar onde há problemas.

Comment: Kkkkk, se eu pudesse, eu faria era pedir pra olharem meu código toda fez que eu fizesse algo pra saber se existe uma maneira de fazer melhor ou se estou fazendo da maneira correta ou errada kkkkkk e o cara reclamando pq ele falou que deveria ter usado um `while` =/. Adoro ver alguém dizendo a maneira de fazer e explicando o porque, fico mais tranquilo e confiante escrevendo a linha de código kkkk