# Como decidir entre usar for ou foreach?

Tags: c#, foreach, for

Quando devo escolher entre usar o `for` ou `foreach`?

Ambos fazem praticamente a mesma coisa, e eu mesmo sempre me pergunto se estou utilizando a opção "correta"...

Minha dúvida aumenta quando pessoas dizem pra utilizar o `for` por *"ser mais performático"* e outros dizem pra usar o `foreach` pelo código ficar mais legível. Porém o **@Maniero** mostra que pode acontecer o contrário **[nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/53850/foreach-ou-lambda-em-listas/53857#53857)**, e que o `foreach` pode sim ser mais rápido que o `for`.

- Sendo assim, como é possível saber quando utilizar um ou o outro em questões como performance, flexibilidade, fácil manutenção e integração **por exemplo**?
- Quais parâmetros devo analisar ou levar em consideração para decidir qual pode ser mais vantajoso?

Comment: Acho que essa diferença de performance é tão mínima, e nunca é o gargalo em um software, normalmente fazemos outras coisas tão grotescas que isso ai é ínfimo.

Comment: @Dorathoto A dúvida não é apenas sobre performance, editei a pergunta, pra ver se ficou um pouco mais fácil de enter o que eu quero :)

Comment: Se poderia colocar um contexto, um código, uma particularidade, porque, eu acho que é mais especulação do que um fato, veja, a pergunta é boa, mas, vai gerar muitas opiniões porque falta o contexto de aplicação. Usar `for` ou `foreach` é mais layout do que certo ou errado.

Comment: Não sei se ajuda, mas como regra geral eu sigo a seguinte, quando eu não sei quantos elementos irei iterar no laço eu utilizo `foreach`, quando eu sei utilizo `For`, por outro lado o `foreach` usa mais recursos nas iterações

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Vou falar de coleções, mas entenda que sejam todos os tipos enumeráveis.

## Semântica

É uma questão semântica. Você está percorrendo uma coleção (*array*, lista, *string*, dicionário, estrutura JSON, conjunto de dados de um DB, etc.)? Então o `foreach` é bem adequado, ele foi feito para isso, ele pega a coleção e analisa item por item, é exatamente o que você quer. É mais conveniente.

## Segurança

Ele costuma ser mais seguro, robusto, confiável já que torna difícil errar, alguns erros são impossíveis nele, e mais legível porque indica o que vai fazer: varrer uma coleção.

## Não faz o que precisa, de forma conveniente

Mas tem lá suas idiossincrasias também. Ele usa a coleção de forma imutável, se é o que deseja, e quase sempre é, ele é ótimo, mas se precisa modificar a coleção (não estou falando dos itens dela) aí, hoje (não sei no futuro), só o `for` resolve para você.

Outra idiossincrasia é que ele pega o valor por cópia e muitas vezes você faz operações que parecem que é uma referência, mas não é. Mas já está aí as estruturas por referência (`ref`) que podem minimizar isto.

[Tem coleção que não possui ordem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/168531/101) e o `foreach` é a única forma de percorrer corretamente.

Tem casos que precisa fazer algo que o `foreach` **não suporta**, por exemplo se precisar um `await` na coleção. Mas tem [proposta para aceitar um `foreach await`](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/840).

Se precisa **varrer a coleção ao contrário** não tem como usar o `foreach` e parece que não querem colocar um `foreachreverse` na linguagem, apesar das inúmeras propostas. Tem [paliativo com custo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.reverse?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_Reverse__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__).

#### Índice

Outro ponto bem importante é quando precisa do **índice** do item. Algumas linguagens proveem o índice se você quiser no `foreach`, mas a maioria não oferece isto, então se precisa, não tem muito jeito, o `for` é sua solução, ele exige o uso de uma variável de índice para que você acesse o item manualmente. C# não oferece o índice, um dos motivos de ter o `for`.

É possível criar uma estrutura onde você passa uma coleção e recebe o valor do item junto com o índice, aí poderia usar o `foreach` até no caso de precisar do índice, mas a performance é pior e fica feio (ainda que isto seja subjetivo).

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Linq;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var lista = new[] { "abc", "def", "ghi" };
        foreach (var item in lista.Select((value, i) => (i, value ))) {
            WriteLine($"{item.i} => {item.value}");
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wrUSXf). E [no **repli.it**](https://replit.com/join/mcrewdhlyy-maniero). [Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Algorithm/ForeachIndex.cs).

## Flexibilidade

O `for` "puro" é um mecanismo ligeiramente de mais baixo nível e deveria ser evitado, mas não renegado como muitos o fazem. Tem linguagens que nem tem um `for`, algumas sequer o [`while` que tem semântica semelhante, mas não igual](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/157512/101). Você pode andar em passos de variadas formas. Um `for` é um `while` "enfeitadinho", apenas por coincidência ele varre uma coleção.

## Performance

Se precisa dela e a linguagem oferece melhor performance para aquele caso específico usando o `for` no lugar do `foreach` pode ser mais interessante seu uso. Tem que medir, afinal se precisa da performance você já fez medições. Não é para correr pro mais rápido sem sequer saber se precisa e qual é mais rápido. Em muitos casos o C# é tão ou mais rápido usando o `foreach` do que fazendo manual, ele consegue otimizar melhor eliminando verificações desnecessárias porque ele pode provar que não fará acesso em item indevido fora da faixa existente.

Tem casos que a **performance** do `foreach` pode ser bem pior, dependerá do enumerador utilizado. Tem casos que até criará um algoritmo exponencial sem querer, e isto é trágico. Não tem nada de diferença trivial em um caso assim. Claro que precisa saber como não entrar em um O(n<sup>2</sup>) usando o `for`, não é simples, mas pelo menos ele permite você otimizar (não em todos os casos, tem problemas que são exponenciais mesmo).

## Contagem

Se o que você varrerá não é uma coleção então o `for` provavelmente será uma opção mais interessante, afinal aí você está fazendo uma contagem, está evoluindo uma sequência, possivelmente criando uma coleção nova, então não faz sentido usar um `foreach`.

Há uma [proposta para C# ter *ranges*](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/198), aí o `foreach` poderá ser usado até mesmo quando não tem uma coleção. Na verdade isto já pode ser usado com [`Enumerable.Range()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.range?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_Range_System_Int32_System_Int32_), mas costuma ser esquisito o seu uso na maioria dos casos, me parece uma forçação para usar o `foreach` onde não precisa. De fato a criação deste método foi para uso com LINQ que tem *foreachs* internos e precisa de uma solução assim. No fim não ajudou muito quando foi implementado, mas o pessoa tem feito algumas adições para poder usar o *range* de forma direta.

Só lembre que um `for` não é só para fazer uma contagem. Muitas pessoas acham que só um `for (var i = 0; i < c.Length; i++)` pode ser usado, mas qualquer das três partes pode ter quase qualquer coisa, o primeiro e terceiro são *statements*, espera-se uma inicialização ali, mas pode fazer outras coisas, pode fazer várias inicializações, pode fazer nada. O terceiro é um passo, pode colocar o que quiser que seja executado em cada passo da repetição, em geral não faz sentido deixar em branco, mas pode. O segundo precisa ser uma expressão booleana e até pode ficar em branco, apesar de não ser muito adequado. Até isto funciona:

```
for (;;)
```

[O que isso faz?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/174153/101)

E note que `for` ou `foreach` são comandos e não funções por isso o "correto" é `for ()` e não `for()`. Ambos funcionam igual, mas o segundo parece que é uma função, dá a ideia errada.

## Conclusão

Embora funcione em qualquer caso, tem certo e tem errado. Você viaja do Rio para SP de moto, carro, caminhão, ônibus ou avião, cada um tem uma vantagem, estão aí as diretrizes para escolher.

Answer (score 2):

> Ambos fazem praticamente a mesma coisa...

Ambos fazem a mesma coisa quando pensamos em percorrer uma coleção.

> Sendo assim, como é possível saber quando utilizar um ou o outro?

Depende da sua necessidade, o `for` **executa uma operação N vezes**, enquanto que o `foreach` **executa uma operação em todos objetos/valores da coleção especificada**. Perceba que o for tem bem mais uso que o foreach, já que o foreach serve basicamente para iterar sobre uma coleção.

> Quais parâmetros devo analisar ou levar em consideração para decidir
>   qual pode ser mais vantajoso?

Questão de benchmark, como você mesmo citou, vai depender do caso em qual um é mais performatico que o outro.

O foreach deve ser utilizado em um contexto ao qual eu vou percorrer todos os objetos/valores da minha coleção. O `foreach` acaba funcionando em qualquer IEnumerable já que ele utiliza o GetEnumerator() para realizar sua operação, enquanto que o `for` só possui lógica utilizar em coleções ao qual eu posso utilizar um index (arrays e coleções de IList).

Existe casos de limitação também. Exemplo é que o foreach não permite você adicionar ou remover itens dentro da coleção enquanto você interagem sobre ele. Se você precisa fazer isso, é necessário utilizar o for ou fazer um clone da coleção.

Answer (score 1):

De uma maneira geral, há *benchmarks* por ai mostrando que a diferença entre eles não é tão grande na maioria dos cenários, mas há alguns específicos que tem uma diferença.

Veja nesse *benchmark* por exemplo que mostra a interação dos dois comandos em vários tipos de objetos, e em particular com um `DataTable` (ainda se usa muito???) a performance do `foreach` é superior, no cenário de teste proposto é claro:  http://cc.davelozinski.com/c-sharp/for-vs-foreach-vs-while

Já esse outro *benchmark* mostra uma diferença pouco relevante entre os dois: https://www.dotnetperls.com/for-foreach

Concluindo, a não ser que você tenha um cenário bem específico, acredito que seja mais uma questão de preferência usar um ou outro. Claro que um loop `foreach` aparenta ser mais legível, mas depende do tipo de coleção que você está usando (array, dicionário, lista, etc).

Por fim, no **Stackoverflow** em inglês, tem um post legal sobre o assunto, que aborda outros aspectos além de performance, que tem também outros resultados para comparação: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365615/in-net-which-loop-runs-faster-for-or-foreach

Answer (score 1):

A diferença entre eles é bem sutil, que não penso que modificará o desempenho do seu código. Mas caso esse nível de desempenho seja importante para você( estamos falando de 2 vezes ou 5 vezes mais rápido), te aconselho a mudar a linguagem para uma de mais baixo nível. Entretanto, segue [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/365658/8160852) uma resposta que achei no [stackOverflow EN](https://stackoverflow.com/).

> - Ciclos *for* sao um pouco mais que 2 vezes mais baratos que ciclos
> - *foreach* em Listas. Iterando em um *Array* é mais ou menos 2 vezes mais econômico que iterar em uma Lista.
> - Como consequência, ciclos em *Array* usando *for* é 5 vezes mais barato que
>     ciclos em *List* usando *foreach*(Que creio que seja o que nos fazemos).

Answer (score 1):

Tudo depende da sua necessidade, eu acho que primeiramente vem a sua necessidade de manipular/percorrer aquela coleção. Por exemplo:

Eu sempre utilizo `for` quando preciso manipular os objetos que estou percorrendo, pois no `foreach` é como se fosse criado uma cópia temporária do objeto e se você modifica-lo não irá afetar o mesmo dentro da coleção. Tem também a vantagem de você saber qual posição o objeto se encontra dentro da coleção. Outro caso onde eu utilizo `for` é quando preciso percorrer apenas determinadas posições, no `foreach` você não consegue pois você percorre da posição 0 a X.

Eu uso o `foreach` em casos onde eu preciso percorrer toda a lista sem exceção.

Essas são só algumas situações que me fazem decidir entre um ou outro. Caso ambas estejam de acordo com o que você precisa, eu acho que você tem que recorrer a performance, percorrer uma lista inteira por exemplo pode ser custoso e utilizar o mais rápido e eficiente pode ser a melhor opção.