# Automatizar abertura de arquivos sequencial?

Tags: java, arquivo, stream-de-arquivos

Estou querendo abrir vários arquivos binários em Java de uma única vez, porém não quero instanciar todos manualmente dessa forma como segue em exemplo. Existe uma forma automática, ou um método para que eu possa agilizar isso?

Exemplo:

```
File arquivo  = new File("temp0.bin");
FileInputStream fis0  = new FileInputStream(arquivo);
DataInputStream dis0  = new DataInputStream(fis0);

arquivo  = new File("temp1.bin");
FileInputStream fis1  = new FileInputStream(arquivo);
DataInputStream dis1  = new DataInputStream(fis1);

arquivo  = new File("temp2.bin");
FileInputStream fis2  = new FileInputStream(arquivo);
DataInputStream dis2  = new DataInputStream(fis2);

arquivo  = new File("temp3.bin");
FileInputStream fis3  = new FileInputStream(arquivo);
DataInputStream dis3  = new DataInputStream(fis3);
```

Comment: Wesley, nao precisa citar a linguagem no titulo, uma vez que a pergunta já possui a tag, fica redundante.

Comment: Primeira vez aqui, vou pegar o jeito ainda.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 1):

Isto?

```
ArrayList<File> arquivo = new ArrayList<File>();
ArrayList<FileInputStream> fis = new ArrayList<FileInputStream>();
ArrayList<DataInputStream> dis = new ArrayList<DataInputStream>();
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    arquivo.add(new File("temp" + i.toString() + ".bin");
    fis.add(new FileInputStream(arquivo));
    dis.add(new DataInputStream(fis0));
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Algorithm/OpenFiles.java).

Sempre que precisa variar algo use uma variável. Sempre que há uma repetição use um laço [`while` ou `for`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/157512/101). Se precisa manter vários estados utilize um [*array*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/199751/101) ou uma [lista](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73633/101).

Comment: Então eu até poderia fazer isso mas eu preciso todos os arquivos aberto, dessa forma caso eu não esteja enganado, o dis0 estará associado apenas ao ultimo arquivo.

Comment: Assim? Dá pra fazer melhor que isto, mas depende de coisas mais avançadas que ainda não deve saber.

Comment: Dá sua sujestão dai eu falo se tenho conhecimento sobre ou não, mas então qual sua ideia um arraylist de DataInputStream, estive pensando nisso só não tenho certeza se é viável.

Comment: Obs: quando estava digitando você atualizou!.

Comment: Nesse caso acho que só preciso do ArrayLIst do Data input, os outros valores são dispensáveis, daí não há necessidade de persisti-los.

Comment: Eu acho que várias coisas podem ser feitas mas o seu exemplo e descrição do problema é muito limitado, então não posso fazer do jeito que eu faria porque pode não atender seu caso.

Comment: Então mas vlw, isso já será o bastante para eu conseguir resolver meu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Algo assim? É possível a partir do Java 7:

```
File raiz = new File("/home/usuario/Documents/files/");
File[] files = raiz.listFiles();

for (File file : files) {
  if(file.isFile() && file.getName().endsWith(".bin")){
   //   ...
  }
}
```

No java 8 ainda pode usar lambdas caso queira tb:

```
Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get("."),
    path -> path.toString().endsWith(".bin"))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Não meu problema dá para resolver com o arraylist mesmo, funções anônimas são legais, porém java não usei ainda também não deixa o código muito legível, só em haskell que usei mais.
Mas vlw pela sua contribuição.