# Ajuda com pg_fetch_assoc

Tags: php

Tenho a variável `$result` que me retorna o resultado de uma consulta.

Faço um while nela e pego todas as informações:

```
$total = 0;
while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo "<tr><td>".$row['no_unidade']."</td><td>".$row['no_pessoa_fisica']."</td><td style='text-align:right;'>".$row['count']."</td></tr>";
  $total += $row['count'];
}
```

Visto que o campo `no_unidade` é igual em todas as linhas. Decidi incluir essa linha antes do while, ficando assim:

```
$row= pg_fetch_assoc($result);

echo '<h1 style="text-align:center;">'.$row['no_unidade'].'</h1>';

$total = 0;
  while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<tr><td>".$row['no_unidade']."  </td><td>".$row['no_pessoa_fisica']."</td><td style='text-align:right;'>".$row['count']."</td></tr>";
  $total += $row['count'];
}
```

Assim adiciono a linha que repete na parte de cima e listo os resultados embaixo. Porém, quando faço isso, o primeiro resultado some... E só são listados do segundo em diante.

Como faço pra corrigir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça um [do-while](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.do.while.php), exemplo:

```
$row = pg_fetch_assoc($result);

echo '<h1 style="text-align:center;">'.$row['no_unidade'].'</h1>';

$total = 0;

do 
{
      echo "<tr><td>".$row['no_unidade']."  
          </td><td>".$row['no_pessoa_fisica']."
          </td><td style='text-align:right;'>".$row['count']."</td></tr>";

      $total += $row['count'];

} while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result));
```

Essa estrutura no seu caso em especifico é ideal, porque, precisa pegar informações da primeira linha e imprimir como cabeçalho e antes que seja executada a condição no `while` é impresso também os dados dessa primeira linha.

Aqui no site já tem uma explicação: [Qual a diferença entre o while, for, do while e foreach?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/157512/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-o-while-for-do-while-e-foreach), boa leitura.

<sub>Referencia: [do-while](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.do.while.php)</sub>

Comment: funcionou. pode me explicar porque assim funciona?

Comment: @ItaloRodrigo fiz uma edição e coloquei o que acontece, é que nesse caso a condição só executado depois da primeira execução, diferente do seu while que antes de entrar no while é feito uma verificação ...

Comment: @ItaloRodrigo entendeu?

Comment: Entendi sim, muito bem explicado. Abraço