# Qual a diferença entre executar códigos dentro das chaves do "for" ou fora delas?

Tags: javascript, c, for, estilo-de-codificação

Em JavaScript ou em C, existe alguma diferença entre usar o `for` do jeito normal:

```js
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
   console.log(i);
}
```

ou executar os códigos dentro dos parenteses? Exemplo:

```js
for(var i = 0; i < 10;
   i++,
   console.log(i)
){}
```

Comment: Clareza do código.

Comment: @anonimo Nesse caso específico, faz diferença nos números que são impressos: o primeiro loop imprime de 0 a 9 e o segundo, imprime de 1 a 10. Veja [aqui](https://ideone.com/AXpZaB) e [aqui](https://repl.it/repls/AlertImpoliteProfessionals)

Comment: @hkotsubo: sim, mas se fizer: `console.log(i), i++` não haverá nenhuma diferença em termos de execução, o que, em minha opinião, é mais um argumento para evitar o uso.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

É uma questão de intenção, este tipo de laço tem uma construção com 3 partes em sua declaração:

- uma inicialização de estado de controle dos passos de cada execução, e todas variáveis envolvidas nisso deveriam ser declaradas ali, não fora, não dentro, deve ser no `for` (tem algum caso que faz sentido declarar fora), e não deve declarar variáveis internas que não façam parte desse controle. Só acontece uma vez no início antes de tudo;
- uma condição de saída que é executada e verificada no fim de cada passo, e só continua o laço se a condição for verdadeira, dá para abusar mas só deveria fazer a condição básica, não inventar coisas (sempre tem algo caso que pode ser útil abusar, mas tem que ter muita noção do que está fazendo e ser muito necessário).
- uma instrução de execução obrigatória no fim de todos os passos, não deve colocar nada ali que não altere as condições de execução do laço. É abuso colocar outras coisas ainda que funcione e obtenha o resultado esperado.

Depois tem o bloco de execução que não faz parte da construção do `for` em si.

Mas tem uma mudança semântica importante em um caso específico. Já respondi em [Qual a diferença entre o while, for, do while e foreach?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/157512/101).

Na forma apresentada não muda nada, mas se tiver alguma condição no meio que possa fazer um desvio dentro do laço e não executar todas instruções dentro dele então faz diferença, o que está no `for` executará em todos os passos que ocorrerem, o que está no bloco pode ser condicional e dá resultado diferente. É importante fazer esta distinção porque pode parecer que sempre é a mesma coisa colocar ali. É igual neste caso porque sabemos que não há um condicional dentro do bloco que impede a execução de alguma instrução em algum passo.

E se tiver que quebrar linhas para fazer isto fica bem feio e mostra que não é o jeito adequado. Estética conta em códigos bem feitos. As pessoas esperam que um `for` esteja em uma linha e faça um controle de passo simples. Quando inventa complica para quem for ler seu código, ela tem que pensar um pouco mais para entender o que você inventou ali.

Por isso algumas linguagens nem gostam deste tipo de `for` bruto, para não dar margem para abusos. Eu gosto de linguagens poderosas e flexíveis, f0d@-se quem não sabe programar e abusa do recurso.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Acho que aquela tua imagem do fiat destruido cairia bem aqui

Comment: Esse caso não acho grave, inclusive o AP parece ter consicência que isto pelo menos pode ter uma diferença, não é como o pessoal que você vê que vai fazer gambiarra só porque funciona, e no exemplo da pergunta não dá para dizer que está errado, só é feio.

Answer (score 6):

O `for` é composto de 4 blocos, conforme explica a [documentação MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for):

```
(inicialização; condição; expressão final){
   declaração
}
```

O bloco `expressão final` é executado após cada iteração do laço. Com isso, se você colocar o `console.log(i)` na `expressão final`, o valor inicial de `i` será `1`, pois o `i++` só será executado após a primeira volta do laço, ou seja, irá imprimir o valor de `i` no console de `1` a `10`, mesmo a condição sendo `i < 10`, pois a expressão final ainda será executada **mais 1 vez** quando a condição não for mais atendida.

No caso do `i` dentro da `declaração`, o valor inicial será `0` (valor declarado na inicialização), pois o `i++` só será executado após a primeira volta do laço, ou seja, o valor de `i` será de `0` a `9`.

Logo, a diferença é que o código na `expressão final` é executado após cada volta do laço, enquanto que na `declaração` é o contrário: antes de cada volta.